# Why is GLFWVidMode not accessible in LWJGL 3.1.1?

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw, eclipse-oxygen

My class says that the import `org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode` is not accessible when I hover over it. I have `lwjgl-glfw.jar` library and all of its natives added to my classpath. I already tried removing them and adding them again. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A wrap-around I am working with is changing the import code for glfw.

From `import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;`
I changed it to `import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;`

For me, although the code accessing GLFWVidMode is underlined in red with the error message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from GLFWVidMode to GLFWVidMode," no errors come up anywhere else and the program starts with no problems.